# c# datagridview key handling

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I use DataGridView, and in some places I add control to it (e.g. textbox, combobox)

```
 dataGridView1.Controls.Add(comboBox);
 comboBox.Focus();
```

The problem is that using this control, and than commiting choice by using ENTER cause the DataGridView to "handle" the key -> after clickng enter instead of choosing sth from combobox, the selection in datagridview changes( moves to next cell).

I use sth like :

```
   public class MyDataGridView:DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if(keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

But it cause that datagridview and combobox doesn't answer to ENTER, and other keys...

Additional infromation: I must use ComboBox class, instead of DataGridViewCombobox. Can anyone help me how to handle ENTER in my comobox?

Comment: You showed me the way to solve a similar problem. I posted a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108791/edit-a-textbox-cell-in-datagridview-as-if-it-were-a-normal-textbox-no-jumping-o) I think you must handle ENTER within the overriding ProcessCmdKey. I didn't find any other way.

Comment: Did you solve it? I think you could hold a reference to your ComboBox in MyDataGridViewClass so you can manipulate it from within ProcessCmdKey method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if((keyData == Keys.Enter) && (MyComboBox.Focused))
```

so DataGridView responds to ENTER except when your control is focused.

I am not sure the following code fits your situation, but maybe you could try something like:

```
public class MyDataGridView:DataGridView
{
    public ComboBox MyComboBox { get; set; } //in case you had no other way to refer to it

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if((keyData == Keys.Enter) && (MyComboBox.Focused))
        {
            //commit choice logic
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

and from your form, if it needs, set the reference to your ComboBox:

```
dataGridView1.Controls.Add(comboBox);
dataGridView1.MyComboBox = comboBox;
comboBox.Focus();
```