# Edit a TextBox cell in DataGridView as if it were a normal TextBox (no jumping on pressing arrows)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have "multiline" (wordwrapping) textbox columns in a DataGridView. It would be great to be able to edit them as normal TextBoxes, that is, **when I press down arrow, I want the caret to go down one line within the textbox, I don't want it to jump to the next row, as it normally does**. Likewise, **I want that pressing enter creates a new line within the textbox cell, but it instead finishes editing**.

Otherwise said: I want to override normal behaviour of some keypresses (or keydowns), so that user can edit a textbox cell as if it were a normal textbox, and navigate inside it with arrows and create new lines with enter.

I tried manipulating keydown events in DataGridView, but it didn't work.

Thank you for any ideas or comments.

Comment: `when I press down arrow, the caret goes down one line within the textbox, it does not jump to the next row` - Is this expected or not ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal, I changed first paragraphs to make my purpose clearer. Thanks for pointing out ambiguity.

Comment: Have you seen the behaviour in `MS-EXCEL` ? Just open a spreadsheet and try. `If you HIT F2 on a cell, then it goes into Editing Mode. And, to go to a new line whle editing you have to use ALT+Enter.` **But**, just pressing the `Enter` key `ends the editing` and moves to the new row / cell below. So, just asking -- why do  you want to move away from standard functionality ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Alt+Enter also finishes editing, unlike in MS Excel. Standard functionality is OK for single line content of cells, but when editing multiline text, you cannot move up and down within the text and cannot create new lines, or at least I don't know how.

Comment: Its ok to mark your own answers... especially when it works and there are no other posted solutions..

Comment: Thx Jeremy, I will as long as there are no better solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290203/c-sharp-datagridview-key-handling) showed me a way to solve it. Here is the code:

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((keyData == Keys.Enter) && (this.EditingControl != null))
        {
            //new behaviour for Enter
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)EditingControl;
            int pos = tb.SelectionStart;
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(pos, tb.SelectionLength);
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(pos, Environment.NewLine);
            tb.SelectionStart = pos + Environment.NewLine.Length;
            tb.ScrollToCaret();
            //and do nothing else
            return true;
        }
        else if ((keyData == Keys.Up) && (this.EditingControl != null))
        {
            //programmatically move caret up
            //(look at related question to see how)
            return true;
        }
        else if ((keyData == Keys.Down) && (this.EditingControl != null))
        {
            //programmatically move caret down
            //(look at related question to see how)
            return true;
        }
        //for the rest of the keys, proceed as normal
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

So this is a simple change of DataGridView and it works. I only had to

- **create this new class**, and
- **change two lines from the DesignerClass** to use MyDataGridView instead of DataGridView (declaration and initialization)

and everything else worked as expected.

Related question: [how to programmatically move caret up and down one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123067/programmatically-move-caret-in-textbox-line-up-and-line-down).